# R: data.table .dynamic aggregations on column Date columns

Tags: r, data.table, dynamic-columns

I am trying to do a `min`/`max` aggregate on a *dynamically chosen* column in a `data.table`.  It works perfectly for `numeric` columns but I cannot get it to work on `Date` columns unless I create a temporary `data.table`.

It works when I use the name:

```
dt <- data.table(Index=1:31, Date = seq(as.Date('2015-01-01'), as.Date('2015-01-31'), by='days'))
dt[, .(minValue = min(Date), maxValue = max(Date))]
# minValue   maxValue
# 1: 2015-01-01 2015-01-31
```

It does not work when I use `with=FALSE`:

```
colName = 'Date'
dt[, .(minValue = min(colName), maxValue = max(colName)), with=F]
# Error in `[.data.table`(dt, , .(minValue = min(colName), maxValue = max(colName)),  : 
# could not find function "."
```

I can use `.SDcols` on a numeric column:

```
colName = 'Index'
dt[, .(minValue = min(.SD), maxValue = max(.SD)), .SDcols=colName]
#   minValue maxValue
#  1:        1       31
```

But I get an error when I do the same thing for a Date column:

```
colName = 'Date'
dt[, .(minValue = min(.SD), maxValue = max(.SD)), .SDcols=colName]
# Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
#   only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables
```

If I use `lapply(.SD, min)` or `sapply()` then the dates are changed to numbers.

The following works and does not seem to waste memory and is fast.  Is there anything better?

```
a <- dt[, colName, with=F]
setnames(a, 'a')
a[, .(minValue = min(a), maxValue = max(a))]
```

Comment: Short answer: Use `.SD[[1]]` because `.SD` is a list of vectors and you want to use the first vector in it. Long answer: you seem to have found some weird loophole where a data.frame of all numeric cols can have its `max` and `min` taken; and I wouldn't build on that weird exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your first attempt:

```
dt[, .(minValue = min(colName), maxValue = max(colName)), with=F]
# Error in `[.data.table`(dt, , .(minValue = min(colName), maxValue = max(colName)),  : 
# could not find function "."
```

You should simply read the [Introduction to data.table](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started) vignette to understand what `with=` means. It's easier if you're aware of `with()` function from base R.

On the second one:

```
dt[, .(minValue = min(.SD), maxValue = max(.SD)), .SDcols=colName]
# Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
#   only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables
```

This seems like an issue with `min()` and `max()` on a data.frame/data.table with column with attributes. Here's a MRE.

```
df = data.frame(x=as.Date("2015-01-01"))
min(df)
# Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
#   only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables
```

To answer your question, you can use `get()`:

```
dt[, .(min = min(get(colName)), max = max(get(colName)))]
```

Or as @Frank suggested, `[[` operator to subset the column:

```
dt[, .(min = min(.SD[[colName]]), max = max(.SD[[colName]]))]
```

There's not yet a nicer way of applying `.SD` to multiple functions (because base R doesn't seem to have one AFAICT, and data.table tries to use base R functions as much as possible). There's a [FR #1063](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1063) to address this issue. If/when that gets implemented, then one could do, for example:

```
# NOTE: not yet implemented, FR #1063
dt[, colwise(.SD, min, max), .SDcols = colName]
```

Comment: Thinking about that colwise, ... a clumsy workaround for the OP's case is `dcast(dt, .~., value.var="Date", fun=list(min,max))` or `dcast(dt, .~., value.var=names(dt), fun=list(min,max))` to do both vars at once.